# Get the first word of line when regex pattern match in python

Tags: python, regex

input looks like below and i want the output to be the first interface where status = [up]  : in this example below the output should be Ethernet1/48

```
Last bundled member is Ethernet1/48
Ports:   Ethernet1/45    [active ] [down]
         Ethernet1/46    [active ] [down]
         Ethernet1/47    [active ] [down] *
         Ethernet1/48    [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/1   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/2   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/3   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/4   [active ] [up]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Use a lookahead or `if '[up]' in line`

Comment: honestly i didn't try anything :) , it looked really complicated ( i'll read about lookahead ) , thanks

Comment: Why is there `*` at the end?

Comment: @S.Jovan that's a switch output : * means that this interface was the First operational port of this group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i got it , this code worked :

```
import re

text = """
Last bundled member is Ethernet1/48
Ports:   Ethernet1/45    [active ] [down]
         Ethernet1/46    [active ] [up]
         Ethernet1/47    [active ] [up] *
         Ethernet1/48    [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/1   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/2   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/3   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/4   [active ] [up]
"""


pattern = '\w+\S+(?=\s*\[\w+ \] \[up\])'
result = re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)
print result[0].strip()
```

i've edited the pattern to match other possible outputs like :
if [up] was the first line old patter would also match the ports: word
if the protocol used was not LACP the output would be [on ] [up] and not [active ] [up].

Thanks

Comment: Your `.*` is too greedy. If you change the end of the first `active` line to `up`, it will include the first word as well. Use `\S+` instead.

Comment: Use [`Ethernet\S+(?=\s*\[active \] \[up\])`](https://regex101.com/r/xiuCXW/1/) performs better.

Comment: @S.Jovan: Since OP only wants the first, you could drop the `g` and use https://regex101.com/r/xiuCXW/2

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
import re

string = """
Last bundled member is Ethernet1/48
Ports:   Ethernet1/45    [active ] [down]
         Ethernet1/46    [active ] [down]
         Ethernet1/47    [active ] [down] *
         Ethernet1/48    [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/1   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/2   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/3   [active ] [up]
         Ethernet2/1/4   [active ] [up]
"""

rx = re.compile(r'Ethernet\S+(?=\s*\[active \] \[up\])')
match = rx.search(string)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
```

Which yields

```
Ethernet1/48
```

Comment: thanks but Ethernet could be a different word in other devices so that’s why i used .* for more generic output

Answer (score 0):

This worked

**CODE**

```
test_str = '''
    Last bundled member is Ethernet1/48\n
    Ports:   Ethernet1/45    [active ] [down]\n
             Ethernet1/46    [active ] [down]\n
             Ethernet1/47    [active ] [down] *\n
             Ethernet1/48    [active ] [up]\n
             Ethernet2/1/1   [active ] [up]\n
             Ethernet2/1/2   [active ] [up]\n
             Ethernet2/1/3   [active ] [up]\n
             Ethernet2/1/4   [active ] [up]
             '''

for line in test_str.split('\n'):
    if '[up]' in line:
        tmp_line = line.split(' ')

        flag = False

        for word in tmp_line:
            if word:
                print(word)
                flag=True
                break

        if flag:
            break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Ethernet1/48
```

Comment: thanks for the code , howver can you check my code and let me know your thoughts

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Well done! finding the solution to your own problem :)